# requesting clarification on Unix Switches -t -i

Tags: php, linux, apache

So i understand the directive that tells server to **sendmail** from application in

```
path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

but what i dont understand is what the two switches

```
-t and -i
```

represent and i cannot find them on google or stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `man sendmail`?

**-t**

> Extract recipients from message headers. These are added to any recipients specified on the command line.

**-i**

> When reading a message from standard input, don't treat a line with only a . character as the end of input.

Comment: wow, no i didnt, i was on a research caffeine infused binge, and missed a simple resource....the freakin 'man' pages for sendmail..much obliged

Comment: @Alyosha_Karamazov then you should accept the answer :D